# How to fetch Document Library List in my application?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I want to fetch Document Library List in my application using java-script/Jquery 
How can I fetch SharePoint  Document Library record and show in my application.

Comment: Q.1.Do you want each document name in your library or you are fetching one document based on some condition? Q.2. Does your library have folders in it?

Comment: Q.1. I want each doc name.(List record). Q2. No any folder only doc.

Comment: If you need any help regarding my answer, feel free to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the two easy ways of doing it

1. Using REST Services
2. Using JavaScript Object Model

**1. Using REST**

Using REST services, you can make a REST call to the document library and simply get all the items in an array.

Here the REST call will be: `http://*your site*/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(LibName )/Files`

When the call is completed, the results are stored in `FilesData` array which you can use in your application.

Eg. `var name = FilesData.d.results[i].Name` would get you the name and `var URL = FilesData.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl` will get you the URL of the document. So if you want the document to be downloadable from your application simply store it in a variable as  `var DownloadLink = <a href='" + URL + "'>name</a>`

Note: You can also get other properties like created, modified, created by, modified by, etc.

```
    var LibName = "Documents";
    $("#btn").click(function(){  //btn is the id of the button, you can call this function on any event
     StoreInArray();
});
    function StoreInArray(){
    var CallLibrary = GetListItems();

    $.when(CallLibrary).then(function (FilesData) {
            for (var i = 0; i < FilesData.d.results.length; i++) {
                var name = FilesData.d.results[i].Name;
                var url = FilesData.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl;
            }
       });
    }

    function GetListItems() {
        var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+LibName+"')/Files";
        return $.ajax({
            url: siteURL,
            async: false,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        });
    }
```

**2. Using JavaScript Object Model**

See the msdn link [How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply Mayank. But I want to access sharepoint site in my other application not sharepoint how can I access this in my other application.?

Comment: What languages are you using in your other application?

Comment: Yes, Try the code in my answer, it should work.

Comment: 1. Using REST   :  I get this error when i run "Uncaught ReferenceError: _spPageContextInfo is not defined"

Comment: try giving full url of sharepoint site instead of it. var siteURL = "http://<your site name>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+LibName+"')/Files

Comment: Paste this URL and in your IE address bar, if it doesn't get error then it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53980/discussion-between-mayank-srivastava-and-admin).